# Restore Backlight To Previous Level, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, restore, backlight

I was working on my app recently and wanted to change the brightness of the backlight. I then wanted to restore the backlight level to it's original setting on exiting the app. Here is the code:

```
#include "GraphicsServices.h"

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

NSNumber* bl = (NSNumber*) CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("SBBacklightLevel"),     CFSTR("com.apple.springboard")); // To retrieve backlight settings
    prevBacklightLevel = [bl floatValue];

GSEventSetBacklightLevel(0.5f); 

}

// Other code here...    

- (void)applicationWillTerminate
{
    GSEventSetBacklightLevel(prevBacklightLevel); // To restore to original level
}
```

The backlight changes correctly on loading the app, yet when the user exits, the backlight remains at the level set by the app... how inconvenient!

Can any help me as to why this is not working as expected, am I doing anything obviously wrong?

I could not find much information on the web regarding this issue.

ViewController.h requires

```
#import "GraphicsServices.h"
```

also.

Edit // Can anyone help with this problem:

When  app is closed backlight level does change, but always to 0, no matter what it was at before the app was run. Possibly bl is always 0 for some reason?

Many thanks,

Stu

Comment: If you need additional info to answer this question and I have not provided it, simply comment and I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the answer. It was a really basic error... silly mistake. I had:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate
```

in ViewController.m rather than AppDelegate.m

It now works perfectly.

I hope this helps anyone out there with a similar problem,

Stu

Answer (score 1):

To controll the brightness within the app is an interesting idea. However, using this string will be a cause of rejection. (See the [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6400-adjusting-screen-brightness.html).)

Well, ... I don't know how to restore the level after the user exits. Therefore, let me introduce two APIs to you. They are the way on Mac OS X.

`CFPreferencesSetAppValue()` and `CFPreferencesAppSynchronize()`

If you solve the problem, please write down the correct code for the other developers, include me. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know your the latest post.

Comment: If you are using the same method as I have above, you will need to add the GraphicsServices framework and header to your project. I will change my question to show this.