# Restore backlight level on app exit

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786825/restore-backlight-to-previous-level-iphone) that to restore brightness on app exit you have to use event `applicationWillTerminate`

I do it in the following way

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = initialBackLightLevel;
}
```

and it does not work. Where can be the issue?

Comment: what is the value of initialBackLightLevel? and what ios you are using?

Comment: value is ok, it just does not change [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a iOS bug...check Apple dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/625119